# Ubuntu 17.04 does not boot when enable gdm3

Tags: gnome, gdm, 17.04, gnome-shell

Recently I switched from Ubuntu 16.10 to Ubuntu 17.04. Reading this news, [Ubuntu 18.04 To Ship with GNOME Desktop, Not Unity](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/04/ubuntu-18-04-ship-gnome-desktop-not-unity?utm_source=slideshow), I decided to switch to gnome.

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell gnome
```

At this point all works fine and can start the session using gnome without problems.

But when try to switch to `gdm3` and reboot the system does not boot. Switching back to `lightdm` and the system start ok. Im misssing something?

Comment: The package to switch to gnome-shell under ubuntu should be ubuntu-gnome-desktop. During it's installation it let you choose whether install (and configure I guess) gdm3 or lightdm. Have you tried that?

Comment: Running into same problem. Get stuck on the screen that shows after you type in the Ubuntu boot password (for encrypted disk). If I press Ctrl-C, it advances to a larger screen (running in VirtualBox) that stays black. I did select **gdm3** during installation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Resolved with:

```
apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

the entire install line to switch from unity to gnome should be

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop gnome-shell gnome
```