# Xubuntu 18.0.4 boots to white screen … help please

Tags: boot, xubuntu

☺ I got sick of Windows and switched to Linux on my Lenovo ThinkPad T420 two months ago.  After trying a few distro/flavors I settled on Xubuntu 18.0.4. It was always a little buggy with random program crashes and errors, but it worked fine until last night.

When I rebooted last night, it asked me to unlock my disk and log into my user acct, then it went to a flickering white screen.  I did a little research and figured the problem was "LightDM" went rogue.  So I purged and reinstalled it … same thing. I kept reading and found the problem could have been proprietary Nvidia drivers.  I tried to purge them from recovery but got some "system is in read-only mode" error, even with sudo.

I rebooted again, and now my laptop doesn't even the Lenovo boot screen. It boots straight into a solid white screen.  I tried pressing buttons to get to the boot menu, and they made their usual noises, but the screen stayed white. Please help me! I'm starting college in 2 months and don't have money. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: You don't need money to solve it. check this solutions https://askubuntu.com/questions/908764/display-manager-gdm3-not-working-under-ubuntu-17-04

Comment: ASIL, that link just says to reinstall Ubuntu. I cannot even get to my laptop's pre-boot screen to say to launch from a flash drive. I suppose I could just just look up the keyboard shortcuts and reinstall it without the display. Do you have any leads where to find the shortcuts?

Comment: Okay, so I navigated the BIOS to the boot screen from memory, but I still can't see …