# Post 18.04.1 upgrade dual monitor not working

Tags: nvidia, upgrade, multiple-monitors, hdmi

PROBLEM SUMMARY: Upgraded from 16.04 to 18.04 and 2nd monitor, HDMI, does not connect. I've used Ubuntu for 10+ years, am Linux certified, but I've never had a problem this obtuse. The possible video configurations for 18.04 are very confusing.

STATUS:

- About a month ago I "upgraded" from 16.04. The quotes are because it was a fresh install, and I preserved my /home directory.
- The 2nd monitor is HDMI connected, and my video is Nvidia GF 108GLM [NVS 5200M] on a Dell E6430.
- I've been able to get both monitors working for a week or so, but every update wipes out the setting/environment and I have to restart.
- I've taken WAYLAND out of the gdm3 configuration, I've gone to completely X config, I've successfully installed the Nvidia driver, etc. It's really crazy.
- These steps worked, for about a week: [Display Manager gdm3 not working under Ubuntu 17.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/908764/display-manager-gdm3-not-working-under-ubuntu-17-04/1066697#1066697)

  Any suggestions for a next step ? I've read all the posts I can find.