# ubuntu 20.04 not getting locked after lid close

Tags: nvidia, suspend, power-management, 20.04, hibernate

I have installed the latest ubuntu 20.04 and recently noticed a bug that whenever I close my lid the screen only goes blank instead of going into hibernate or suspend. Earlier after reopening the lid, I was presented with a lock screen.

- I noticed that there is no longer an option in gnome-settings as it was in ubuntu 18.04.
- tried changing the values in /etc/systemd/logind.conf.
- changing values in gnome-tweaks.
- tried installing hibernate from `sudo apt-get install hibernate` and running

  `sudo hibernate`

  getting this error

  `hibernate:Warning: Tuxonice binary signature file not found.
  Some modules failed to unload: nvidia_drm nvidia_modeset nvidia
  hibernate: Aborting suspend due to errors in ModulesUnloadBlacklist (use --force to override)`

How to resolve this?

Comment: Solved it by changing the display manager from ligthdm to gdm3

Answer (score -1):

Yes, changing the display manager to GDM3 worked for me as well.  It was as simple as:

```
sudo apt-get install gdm3
```

During the install process a screen pops up that allows you to choose GDM3 instead of LightDM.  Choose GDM3!

Before that though, I made several failed attempts to install other display managers such as SLIM, CDM, XDM, etc.  I spent hours trying to "compile" and "make" (a bit over my head) and they were all dead ends.

Comment: When I had LightDM on my 20.04 system, when I would shut the lid it kept running (didn't suspend like it should).  When I opened the lid all I got was a permanent blank screen that required a hard shutdown.

Comment: gdm3 is not compatible with nvidia. Only lightdm works see this thread https://askubuntu.com/questions/908764/display-manager-gdm3-not-working-under-ubuntu-17-04